# Need help understanding why I'm getting not-a-number output with computing imaginary Numbers

Tags: javascript, complex-numbers

```
function ImaginaryNumbers(realNum, imaginary) {
this.realNum = 0;
this.imaginary = 0;
this.realNum = (typeof realNum === 'undefined') ? this.realNum : parseFloat(realNum);
this.imaginary = (typeof imaginary === 'undefined') ? this.imaginary : parseFloat(imaginary);  
}

ImaginaryNumbers.transform = function(num) {
var imaginaryNumbers;
imaginaryNumbers = (num instanceof ImaginaryNumbers) ? num : imaginaryNumbers;
imaginaryNumbers = (typeof num === 'number') ? new ImaginaryNumbers(num, 0) : num;
return imaginaryNumbers;
};

function display_complex(re, im) {
if(im === '0') return '' + re;
if(re === 0) return '' + im + 'i';
if(im < 0) return '' + re + im + 'i';
return '' + re + '+' + im + 'i';
}

function addingComplexNumbers(first, second, third, fourth) {
var num1;
var num2;
num1 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(document.getElementById("firstComplexNumber").value);
num2 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(document.getElementById("secondComplexNumber").value);
num3 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(document.getElementById("thirdComplexNumber").value);
num4 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(document.getElementById("fourthComplexNumber").value);
var realNum = num1.realNum + num2.realNum + num3.realNum + num4.realNum;
var imaginary = num1.imaginary + num2.imaginary + num3.imaginary + num4.imaginary;
return document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = display_complex(realNum, imaginary);
}
```

I try to get the users input but I keep getting `NaN` + `NaNi` as the following result. I'm not sure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting value from Input as number but as string so use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get an integer entered.

Current is:

```
num1 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(document.getElementById("firstComplexNumber").value);
num2 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(document.getElementById("secondComplexNumber").value);
num3 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(document.getElementById("thirdComplexNumber").value);
num4 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(document.getElementById("fourthComplexNumber").value);
```

Change to:

```
num1 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(parseInt(document.getElementById("firstComplexNumber").value));
num2 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(parseInt(document.getElementById("secondComplexNumber").value));
num3 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(parseInt(document.getElementById("thirdComplexNumber").value));
num4 = ImaginaryNumbers.transform(parseInt(document.getElementById("fourthComplexNumber").value));
```